# Delay doctrine event listener in Symfony to send webhooks

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Every time a new Invoice is created in the database, I want to send a request to a webhook URL that my client has configured.

For that, I am using Doctrine's EventSubscriber.

At the moment, I have implemented the following code, which does work:

```
class WebhookSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    
public function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        Events::postUpdate,
        Events::postPersist,
    ];
}

public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    // Send POST request to the client's URL
}

public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    // Send POST request to the client's URL
}

}
```

My problem is the following:

On `postPersist`, meaning when I use `entityManager->flush()`, the event is immediately dispatched.

But it appears that I do multiple flushes in order to create my Invoice, and so when the event is dispatched, the Invoice's data that is sent to my client are not complete.

Is there something that I can add that waits for the entire process to end, so that when I send my hook, everything is complete and my client has every single information on its invoice?

Comment: Coupling your domain logic to Doctrine events is a bad idea. Move that logic from there somewhere else. Where exactly depends on your system design, but wherever you handle the new object creation is where you should dispatch your "send this to X" behaviour. Coupling Doctrine events with external integrations seem like a great way to decrease performance and find yourself with unexpected (and unrelated) failures.

Answer (score 0):

Are you filtering your event entity? When you call flush in any entity Event Subscriber will dispatch and run on every entity. You must filter the entity to avoid event to dispatch on every entity. e.g

```
public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args): void
{
    $entity = $args->getObject();

    // if this listener only applies to certain entity types,
    // add some code to check the entity type as early as possible
    if (!$entity instanceof Product) {
        return;
    }

    $entityManager = $args->getObjectManager();
    // ... do something with the Product entity
}
```